# What are different battery capacity algorithms used?

Tags: battery-charging, electrical, battery-chemistry, algorithm

I need to implement an algorithm to know the capacity of a battery. I don't want to use any external gauges which are available on the market.

1. Can you suggest which algorithm(s) is/are popular?
2. Can we implement any algorithm ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

There is as far as I know:

- Coulomb Counting, where you integrate the current, flowing into or out of the battery.
- Voltage Measurement, where you measure the voltage of the battery
- IT - Impedance Tracking,
- CEDV - Compensated End of Discharge

Point 3 and 4 are found with TI Chips bq-something.

I know a lot of older E-Bikes use coulomb counting and OCV measurement in parallel, where CC is the primary gauging and OCV a backup verification process.

CC consists of the actual coulomb counting algorithm and a teaching algorithm, which calculates the Full Charge Capacity based upon End of Charge Voltage and End of Discharge Voltage.

Edit:
Cheap chinese manufactured batteries only rely on Voltage measurement, although this method has a large margin of error, depending on the load.

Comment: thank you alexander ,can we implement ourselves  without any ic's in any microcontroller?

Comment: @mani CC and Voltage you can implement yourself, you only need one or more ADCs.

Comment: @mani For the Voltage measurement type you need the discharge curve of the battery, you can receive it from your supplier (normally)

Comment: which algorithm is more accurate and why ?

Comment: @mani Don't ask new questions as a comment, create a new question or edit the existing question.

Comment: @ELLIOT ALDERSON 
okay